# Upgrading to SharePoint 2013 / SharePoint 2016

Tags: migration

I note in Microsoft documentation that there is a minimum database build of Service Pack 1 (SP1) with March 2013 PU, version 15.0.4481.1005 or higher for a database attach upgrade from SP 2013 to SP 2016. However I can't find any similar minimum requirement for upgrading to SP 2013 from SP 2010. Does anyone know if there is a SP 2010 Database minimum build requirement for upgrading to SP 2013?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such requirement but it is highly advised that make sure your farm is up to date and in healthy state.

Reason is when we do the database attach upgrade it is only effect Database schema not the site collections. You will get the sites in 2013 as 2010 mode.

Following points MSFT recommend

- make sure 2010 farm is healthy
- test the upgrade in test farm
- don't ignore any error
- test after the upgrade

Check these useful links

http://www.degdigital.com/insights/tips-and-tricks-for-sharepoint-2013-upgrades-and-migrations/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607663

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/step-by-step-upgrade-sharepoint-2010-database-to-sharepoint-2013